# Can we send 'class' or 'array' or 'list' as a parameter in XSLT , just like we are sending 'string' variable as a parameter

Tags: arrays, class, xslt, parameters, arguments

Can we send 'class' or 'array' or 'list' as a parameter in XSLT , just like we are sending 'string' variable as a parameter?

Comment: The conventions for passing parameters to XSLT depend entirely on the XSLT processor and API that you are using, which you haven't told us. (And please don't ask for things ASAP or tell us it's urgent. That's often a hint that people were in too much of a hurry to do their research properly, which makes us less inclined to help you.)

Comment: Thanks for your attention to me , now i got the solution. Thank u sir